# What is the callback url for linked in authorization from metro app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, linkedin-api

I am building a metro application where I will be trying to grab information from a person from their LinkedIn profile such as work history and education. I have done research on how to build the requests, and have been trying to convert the Twitter oauth example for metro apps provided by msdn [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122), which uses webauthenticationbroker.

I have been trying to implement the changes as suggested by [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/b8dec7ba-1c4c-4238-879f-268ee53b13a2/) pertaining to callbackurl errors. I am confused at what the callbackurl actually is for my application if, when the authorization process is over, I would like them to return to my application.

Has anyone performed authorization with linkedin in metro apps? If so, would you mind educating me what the callbackurl would be for my application and if there are any web resources that I have not listed that would assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Couldn't view the forums link, since it appears to be down at the time of writing]

The call back URL is a URL you define, when the navigation happens inside the WebAuthentication popup UI *to* that URL, it detects that and completes the promise it returned. This is the point where you now have the information you need to save off the tokens etc.

The Facebook approach is probably a better sample, since the twitter one is much more focused on signing the query rather than the flow for oAuth.

So, in short, the URL is any URL you define. The remote server will redirect to that URL when things complete, and allow you to extract the information in the value passed to your completed promise handler.

Comment: yeah, that link wasn't working when it was turned into a link, here is the url: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/b8dec7ba-1c4c-4238-879f-268ee53b13a2/

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having? The call back URL really is any (valid) URI you can dream up.

Comment: after reading up more on it, I think my problem is with getting the request token. I think the twitter example will work and I know I am using the proper urls, my program crashes in the PostData() function on the line:

    HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)await; Request.GetResponseAsync();

and it is a 400 HTTP error, bad request.

Comment: my issue was a time stamp problem and my lack of understanding on how oauth flows. I have since gotten it to work but your comments aided the process.

Comment: I got bit by that -- and the content type not being correct for the oauth service i'm using. I wrote a nice WinJS library that's up on git hub, but I don't think that's gonna help you :)